# Catch navbar on scroll and fix it to top

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gsap

I've got a navbar, that currently resides below a page title and sub-heading. I want to "catch" it as I scroll down and fix it to the top once it hits the top of the window so that you can see it while scrolling, and then release it on scroll up.

Hopefully that makes sense. I think probably jquery or greensock would be a good bet for this, but I don't know where to start. I thought maybe I could add bootstrap's navbar-fixed-top class at the point where it hits the top?

```
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  border-radius: 0;
}
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```

Another problem is that the menu collapses into a hamburger on mobile, and I want it to be fixed on mobile scroll too, but it will start at the top of the screen, so I can't just hardcode in the position, unless I do it based on media queries.

http://codepen.io/Kathrynwatts/pen/BjRvRe

Comment: I said I don't know where to start. I know there is a jquery class .addClass, but I have no idea how to tie that to the position of the navbar

Comment: @Seeshi_suin You are looking for `$(window).scroll()`.

Comment: @vanburen, that is basically what I wanted. Thanks so much!

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/444/

Comment: @Paulie_D, sorry, I'm not trying to be obnoxious, I just honestly didn't even know how to start fixing it myself. I'm new to jquery, and I've been googling it for about 30 minutes before I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since you said you don't know how to start, are you looking for something like this?

```js
$(function () {
  h1Top = $("h1").position().top;
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > h1Top)
      $("body").addClass("fixed");
    else
      $("body").removeClass("fixed");
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
p {margin: 10px;}
h1 {background-color: #ccf; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 1.5; text-align: center;}
.fixed h1 {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id similique ipsum, non, natus omnis doloremque accusamus inventore reprehenderit adipisci totam. Hic vel doloremque minus at. Fugiat perferendis ut eum, excepturi.</p>
<p>Minima quas placeat eos veniam quo animi voluptatibus dolores, ipsa aliquam corporis tenetur corrupti eaque eveniet esse repellat dicta incidunt, sint ratione natus. Sequi fugiat officiis iure debitis facilis velit.</p>
<p>Delectus temporibus eos modi recusandae possimus quo tenetur eligendi quaerat assumenda officiis. Ipsum officiis hic sequi rem in neque architecto? Error accusantium doloribus labore minima, enim officiis quidem adipisci harum!</p>
<h1>This will be Fixed to Top</h1>
<p>Dolore natus ipsam eius, temporibus, mollitia quidem veniam illum ipsum. Architecto dolor minima quasi placeat, vero eos tempore voluptatem hic, tenetur cupiditate corrupti quae in id saepe optio nobis ducimus.</p>
<p>Veritatis reprehenderit et illum magni molestias incidunt adipisci ea asperiores tempore sapiente ipsa itaque nobis distinctio quia necessitatibus dolores vitae nemo maxime provident voluptatibus commodi, inventore saepe harum! Ab, unde.</p>
<p>Quod quia deleniti itaque vel a nostrum maxime et hic corporis architecto aperiam ex alias modi odio numquam nemo ipsam illum quis, veniam molestias delectus perferendis ad accusantium voluptatum! Sapiente.</p>
<p>Eum omnis molestias aut dolore, dolores mollitia corrupti perspiciatis repellat deleniti magni consequuntur voluptas nihil obcaecati quos, id, enim dignissimos facere quod quae quo dicta odio. Excepturi, sint amet odio.</p>
<p>Laudantium dolores obcaecati soluta, ut quasi dolore nesciunt. Eaque deleniti doloribus iure laborum nobis, pariatur optio blanditiis est dicta maxime, dolorem, dolores. Esse odit, accusamus quis asperiores totam consequuntur perferendis.</p>
<p>Rerum maiores minima odio quam, numquam modi ex repudiandae. Pariatur illo nemo vero enim totam ad corrupti reiciendis tenetur, voluptatem iure. Cumque optio impedit reiciendis? Maxime quaerat, nemo. Dicta, laboriosam.</p>
<p>Nostrum eligendi tempora ut amet quaerat et suscipit ipsam perferendis neque a omnis quis necessitatibus velit, mollitia sint eaque. Sunt velit esse minus dolore assumenda, beatae tempore voluptas dicta corporis.</p>
<p>Accusantium laborum architecto ab. Vel debitis, error illo delectus voluptate tempore provident nisi! Est beatae inventore velit amet! Ipsa obcaecati et sit. Neque vero amet aliquam minima quibusdam nulla laboriosam?</p>
<p>Dolor commodi dolores, maiores animi porro voluptas pariatur, nulla sit excepturi vel minus. Enim quaerat accusamus laboriosam dolor consequuntur iusto, mollitia nihil, ad numquam saepe ullam ducimus laborum. Veniam, beatae?</p>
<p>Cum inventore, ad qui vitae id pariatur, ipsam rem, quaerat quisquam sequi libero assumenda nobis distinctio aliquid cupiditate. Error dolorum tenetur nulla eius recusandae quo, repellendus distinctio voluptate deserunt officiis.</p>
<p>Minus eaque soluta in voluptas sequi illum architecto dignissimos nobis. Aspernatur culpa, voluptatum asperiores laborum, facere perspiciatis officia totam id quaerat? Aliquid voluptates repellat, quisquam aliquam, ex esse voluptatem architecto!</p>
<p>Porro, totam iure magni ab doloribus. Eum culpa quo qui dolorum vel, perspiciatis, eaque accusamus, cupiditate vero ad magni soluta quos facere quidem ipsum commodi. Rerum, alias architecto aliquid mollitia?</p>
```

**How did I do?** Just using common sense and jQuery.

This is done in a simple way:

1. Get the top offset of the fixed element.
2. Once the window scrolltop crosses it, position it fixed.
3. If not, release it.

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
  $el = $('.navbar'); 
  //if you scroll the navbar off-screen
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 /*height when navbar is offscreen*/ && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){ 
    //set it fixed to the top of the screen
    $('.navbar').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'left': '0'}); 
  }
  //if you scroll the navbar back on screen
  if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50 && $el.css('position') == 'fixed')
  {
    //return it back to its original position
    $('.navbar').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '50px'}); 
  } 
});
```

```css
div.navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
body {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
div#spacer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Some text
<div id="navbar" class="navbar"></div>
<br><br><br><div id="spacer"></div>
other text<br><br>some more text
<div id="spacer"></div><div id="spacer"></div><div id="spacer"></div><div id="spacer"></div>
abc
```